# How to use lite-server for nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, package.json, lite-server

I started a project using lite-server. So far I only used an index.html file and client-side Javascript, but now I want to add server-side JavaScript functionality. How can I configure lite-server to use server.js for routing?
Using just node the command would be

```
node server.js
```

However I start my server like this:

```
lite-server
```

How can I specify that for example if '/someurl' is requested, the url gets resolved using server.js? I assume this can be done in bs-config.json as module.export like

```
module.exports = {
 server: {
    middleware: {
      // overrides the second middleware default with new settings
      })
    }
  }
};
```

What might the right definition for my case?

Comment: > Can I specify using server.js in package.json or bs-config.json?

What do you mean by this?

Comment: You have pretty much everything covered here: https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved it. Instead of using server.js, I have to define bs-config.js to handle the routing.
That's my solution using express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/src/" + "index.html" );
})

app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/src/" + "admin.html" );
})

app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
   res.send('hello');
})

module.exports = {
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    },
    middleware: {
      1: app,
  },
},
port:3001,
};
```

By setting *app* as *middleware* on position 1, lite-server's default behaviour gets overwritten and requests get handled by express.